# Parse and Swift 1.2 issue

Tags: parse-platform, swift

This code worked fine in Swift 1.1 ... just trying to figure out what's changed in 1.2 to make it incompatible:

```
@IBAction func load_click(sender: AnyObject) {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("MPSVivtvJR", block: { (object:PFObject!, error: NSError) -> Void in

        let theName = object["name"] as String
        let theAge = object["age"] as Int?

        println(theName)
        println(theAge)

    })
}
```

It gives me the error: **Cannot invoke 'GetObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type '(String, block: (PFObject!, NSError) -> Void)**

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: According to the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:), `object` should be an NSArray, not a `PFObject!`.

Comment: Thanks, matt--the same error persists, though--even making it an NSArray.

Comment: The NSArray thing is very odd, isn't it? Try structuring your code more like this example from the Parse blog (at end of page): http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/06/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/ Maybe the problem is that you need `NSError!` with an exclamation mark.

Comment: parse SDK v1.7.1 should fix this problem

Comment: Still the same error in my code with SDK v1.7.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now with Swift 1.2 you are supposed to be more careful with unwrapping optionals. So inside the closure where you have `PFObject` and `NSError`, either remove the exclamation marks or add a question mark to make it optional.

Then, unwrap your object more safely. Try as follows:

```
// You can create this in a separate file where you save your models

struct myUser {
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
}

// Now this in the view controller

@IBAction func load_click(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("MPSVivtvJR", block: {
        (object:PFObject!, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let thisName = object["name"] as? String{
            if let thisAge = object["age"] as? Int{
                let user = myUser(name: thisName, age: thisAge)
                println(user)
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: I seem that i m running in the same problem but somehow i can't fix it with that solution could you maybe have a look once @iagomr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577321/parse-getobjectinbackgroundwithid-in-xcode-6-3/29577479

Comment: Worked like charm. but shouldn't you put object["name"]! since object is optional? I had to use "if let .."

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this a lot, but the code below works for me.

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "class")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    var object = query.getFirstObject()

    if let pfObject = object {
        data.variable = (pfObject["variable"] as? Float)!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me.  Here's what did work:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "score")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("j5xBfJ9YXu", block: {
    (obj, error)in
    if let score = obj! as? PFObject {
        println(score.objectForKey("name"))
    } else {
        println(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: also, changing to "if let score = obj! as PFObject?" will remove the compiler error