# Updating object in Parse iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am having trouble translating Parse documentation into new Swift requirements. I want to update an object but I keep getting back an error that I can't assign a value of type `Bool` to type `AnyObject`? I know the column for "viewed" is `Bool`. Here is my code.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.threadImageIds[objectIDkey]) {
  (object, error) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
      println(error)
  } else {
      object["viewed"] = true // this is where error is occuring
      object!.saveInBackground()
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know swift, but I think the error makes clear that object must be typed as PFObject?

Comment: Just a thought, try changing `(object, error)` to `(object: PFObject!, error: NSError!)`

Comment: @danh - that doesn't work either, which is weird because as Portland Runner referenced, it used to be that you had to put 'object: PFObject' and now that isn't even allowed.

Comment: @PortlandRunner - that presents its own error. I had to go back through code and take all of those out after new Swift came out.  Thanks for taking a look

Comment: @FabianBoulegue I tried unwrapping in the way you answered in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435355/parse-and-swift-1-2-issue and I get the same error as mentioned in that post. Wondering if you had any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying to unwrap optionals the way Swift wants me to, the following worked

```
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.threadImageIds[objectIDkey]) {
        (object, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            if let object = object {
                object["viewed"] = true as Bool
            }
            object!.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a `BOOL` there, you need to use a `NSNumber` of a `BOOL`. Try `true as NSNumber`

Comment: I tried this and this doesn't work either. It says that you can't assign type NSNumber to AnyObject?

Comment: This is really odd. Try `NSNumber(bool: true)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you're trying to apply the subscript to the optional and not to the object, so try unwrapping

```
object!["viewed"] = true
```