# Get the current user custom column data in Swift Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

[image: As you can see the picture, this is the User class that allow user to login in my ios application]

As I login via this user to my own application, after I've login, how do I get the custom column data of this user? For example, I want to get the IntakeCode from this user and show it in text field, how to I do that?

I've try this code, but it doesn't work, it says that

> 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!'
>   to force downcast?

```
var displayIntake:NSString = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("IntakeCode")
txtIntake.text = displayIntake as String
```

Hope that someone can help with it, I just want that IntakeCode from this user show in the textfield.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get any custom column using `yourpfobject["yourcolumn"]`..

In your case:

```
if let displayIntake = PFUser.currentUser()!["IntakeCode"] as? String {
    txtIntake.text = displayIntake
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, there're always have the object casting to String problem, but finally I ended up to try your code, and it's worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not working to get integer values! I changed 'as? String' to  'as? Int' but did not work for me!

Comment: @Bernard The value of the column must be an Integer, you can't cast with `as?`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use a query, look into the parse doc for a reference to how to use a query but it should look something like this.

```
var query = PFUser.query
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentUser.username)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil || object == nil {
    println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
  } else {
    // The find succeeded.
            self.intakeCode = object["IntakeCode"] as! String!

    println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
  }
}
```

This query well check the current users username with the database then return anything you call in the background method.

Comment: I will try it once I reach home and tell you whether it works or not :) thanks

Comment: I've tried this code, it shows the error **Cannot invoke 'getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((PFObject!, NSError!) -> Void)'**

Comment: I think before marking a question down you should put more thought into it, if this wasn't you then i am not sure who felt it necessary this is currently how i am accessing my fields in the current user. Currently i am running swift 1.1 with parse 1.7.1 and this works perfectly. 

With the current swift update 1.2 you may want to change the ! to ? optionals e.g.. PFObject? and NSError?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435355/parse-and-swift-1-2-issue

This solves the issue so by making them ? optional you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I did change the PFObject to ? and NSError to ?...But it cant invoke the argument **Cannot invoke 'getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((PFObject?, NSError?) -> Void)'**

Comment: Ok i've edited the answer make sure to call intake as a string at the top of the class and this should work. I haven't fully migrated to Xcode 6.3.1 or swift 1.2 as there is a few errors but after taking a look at swift 1.2 docs and your error is to do with the optionals and unwrapping taking place what i sent should work if you keep getting the same error let me know

Comment: It still have the casting problem, may be we should use this `if let displayIntake = PFUser.currentUser()!["IntakeCode"] as? String {
    txtIntake.text = displayIntake
}`
this is my solution

Comment: I haven't tested in swift 1.2, so you might be right. just going to cause issues with trying to load everything synchronously, which wouldn't work for my application. When i get around to updating, i will let you know if i find a solution.

Comment: By the way, thanks for your help, appreciate that you're trying hard to help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 you just need to

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class newVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var user = PFUser.current()
        print(user?.value(forKey: "isWhat"))
    }
}
```

Here is my parse server:-

[image]

This is my output in viewDidLoad of my View Controller
[image]